# After dictation finished, AutoCorrection is not working in iOS 10 while its working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, ios10

I enabled the dictation in my keyboard setting but still it's not working for iOS 10 for my developed application. While the AutoCorrection is working for my SMS APP.

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Are you changing attributes of string anywhere?

Comment: Yes. I m removing and adding few of my attributes @NikhilManapure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not be adding the attribute for name [`NSTextAlternativesAttributeName`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextalternativesattributename) back to attributed string and that's why suggestions are not coming. You will need to save the value of [`NSTextAlternativesAttributeName`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextalternativesattributename) and add them again while you add your attributes.

That should solve the problem.

Also look at [`NSTextAlternatives`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextalternatives)